# Most straight forward way to retain selected dd option on form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a webform which has validation functions for each field. When I submit the form, if anything fails validation, the user is brought back to the form with the previous values in the input fields and receives some error text.  This is working properly.

The one field which does not retain its selected value/list of values is a dropdown which gets its options via ajax on change of another dropdown.

I've read that one option is to submit the form via ajax but I'd rather not go down that path.

Maybe a function on click for the submit button?

**ajax:**

```
function fillSomeListDropdown(val){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'ajax/somelist.php?q=' + val,
       success: function(data){
            $('#my-id option:not(:first)').remove();
            $('#my-id').append(data);
       }
    });
}
```

**somelist.php**

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$response = sp_things_select_all($q);

// Generate the html
foreach ($response as $value) {
    echo '<option class="option-input" value="' . $value['value'] . '">' . $value['value'] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign val variable before passing it.

```
function fillSomeListDropdown(val){
var val =val;
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'ajax/somelist.php?q=' + val,
       success: function(data){
            $('#my-id option:not(:first)').remove();
            $('#my-id').append(data);
       }
    });
}
```